# Duda sobre hash, md5 y sin encriptar

Tags: php, sql

tenía una duda.

Tengo un login donde tengo una contraseña con hash y el login la validad como tal. Si yo meto una contraseña directamente sin encriptar en la base de datos o hago un update del acontraseña con md5, habría algún tipo de problema en hacer login?

```
<?php session_start();
if (isset ($_SESSION['usuario'])){
  header('Location: ../php/home.php');
}
$errores = '';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST') {
  $email = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $password = hash('sha512', $password);
  try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=drivers_parade_club', 'root', ' ') ;
    // la conexión a la base de datos se hace bien.
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error". $e->getMessage();;
  }
  $statement = $conexion->prepare ('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email AND pass = :password');
  $statement->execute(array(
    ':email'=> $email,
    ':password'=>$password
  ));
  $resultado = $statement->fetch();
  if ($resultado !==false) {
    $_SESSION ['usuario'] = $email;
    header('Location: ../php/home.php');
  }else {
    $errores= '<li style="color:red;"> Tu e-mail o contraseña no son correctos</li>';
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Drivers Parade Club</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
  <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos_login.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/mdb.css">
  <!--Icons CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fontello.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/mdb.min.js"></script>
  <!--Favicon-->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../imagenes/logoprueba.jpg" sizes="64x64"/>
</head>
<body class="imagen">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <nav
          class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light white  scrolling-navbar">
          <div class="text-center">
            <a href="php/contactologin.php" 
              class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" 
              data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactForm">Contacto</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div ></div>
        <!-- Material form login -->
        <div class="card " style="margin-top:25%">
          <h5 class="card-header warning-color white-text text-center py-4 " >
            <strong>Login</strong>
          </h5>
          <!--Card content-->
          <div class="card-body px-lg-5 pt-0">
            <!-- Form -->
            <form 
              class="text-center formulario" 
              style="color: #757575;" 
              action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" 
              method="POST" name="login">
              <!-- Email -->
              <div class="md-form">
                <input type="email" 
                  id="materialLoginFormEmail" class="form-control" name="email">
                <label for="materialLoginFormEmail">E-mail</label>
              </div>
              <!-- Password -->
              <div class="md-form">
                <input type="password" 
                  id="materialLoginFormPassword" class="form-control" name="password">
                <label for="materialLoginFormPassword">Contaseña</label>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                <div>
                  <!-- Forgot password -->
                  <a href=""></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sign in button -->
              <div class="text-center mt-4">
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg  mt-4" 
                  onclick="login.submit()">Login</button>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <?php if(!empty($errores)):?>
                <div class="error">
                  <ul>
                    <?php echo $errores;?>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              <?php endif;?>
              <br>
              <br>
              <!-- Register -->
              <p>¿No eres miembro?
                <a href="php/registro.php">Registrate</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Material form login -->
```

Comment: añade por favor tu código, de otro modo va a ser dificil apoyarte y solo quedará en opiniones pues no sabemos que esta fallando por que no vemos que escribiste; por favor revisa [ask]

Comment: añadido codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Si pones una contraseña sin encriptar en la db la desencriptación no funcionará porque los patrones de encriptado no existen en la contraseña sin encriptar.
Si haces un update a la BD con una nueva contraseña cifrada con el mismo algoritmos de encriptacion, y sigues desencriptandola de la misma manera entonces no habrá problema.

Al momento de crear los usuarios puedes usar

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
```

Esa variable es la que guardas en la bd.

Para hacer el login debes buscar el usuario referenciando el email

```
SELECT * FROM tutabladeusuarios  WHERE email = '".$_POST['emaildelformulario']."'
```

Cuando hagas el `fetch` verificas la contraseña que obtuviste de la db

```
if (password_verify($passworddelformulario, $passworddeladb)) {
    echo "contraseña correcta"
}else{
    echo "contraseña incorrecta"
}
```

Comment: código añadido.

Comment: Osea que si uso md5 para updatear en y el login para validar la pass con hash no funcionaria.no?

Comment: si usas `md5($str)` lo ideal es que para comprobar el login, vuelvas a usar `md5($str)` en la contraseña del formulario y comparar el resultado de la función con lo que hay en tu base de datos.
Puedes visitar [este link](https://gist.github.com/neomadara/b1e0068d1a1a7cb859d5) y [este también](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.storage.php)

Comment: Pra el verificado, no hace falta vereficar con hash si no con password_verify()?

Comment: Sí, en el caso de que uses password_hash()

Comment: Podrías darme un ejemplo con mi código que he puesto por favor?

Comment: Estoy utilizando hash como modo de encriptacion, sería igual que password_hash a la hora de hasearla?

Answer (score -1):

La contraseña se guarda "Hasheada" en la base datos como tal, si por ejemplo tienes en tu Base de Datos un usuario llamado: "pepito", con la contraseña hasheada: "A323F555", y actualizas en la BSD su contraseña con MD5 no habría ningún problema, ya que al iniciar ese login harías una consulta a la BSD y solo comprobaría que la contraseña introducida y la que tiene guardada en el campo contraseña en la BSD sean iguales, si ambas son iguales devolvería *correcto* y harías el login sin problemas!

Comment: Es que estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de validar una contraseña, hay dos usuarios que no funcionan, uno, metiendo a mano la contraseña en bd que por lo que figuras es normal. Y dos, un usuario que desde su perfil a updateado su contraseña con MD5 y después al hacer login no entra